Apache Ignite: partition lost error appears each time after node restart
I'm running an Apache Ignite .Net 2.14 cluster with persistence consisting of three nodes. I noticed that each time any of the nodes restart for any reason, the client application starts failing with the following error: Failed to execute the cache operation (all partition owners have left the grid, partition data has been lost).
I've got familiarized with this error and learned to run control.sh --cache reset_lost_partitions when it happens. However, it means that manual intervention is required every time a nodes restarts and the client application would be down until the error is noticed and the control script is run.
I wonder why this error occurs at all provided the cluster uses persistence, every parition has a backup copy and no data is expected to be lost at node restart? Can it be caused by improper configuration or deployment? If so, what settings should I check?
If this is the expected behaviour then I wonder if there are any plans for changing it in future versions? If no real data loss occurs, that behavior only increases operational complexity and reduces client application's uptime.
Also, I wonder if Grid Gain has the same behaviour. May the migration to that product help?
Thank you in advance.

Most likely you do have some some caches with 0 backups. The system is designed to trigger those errors only in case there's no copy of data left in a cluster. You need to verify that all the caches you interact with the command
control.sh --cache reset_lost_partitions <cache list>

are with 1 (or more) backups and only one node were down.

Thank you for your answer. It happens to all or almost all caches, including the ones having backup copies and the system caches (default-ds-group,default-volatile-ds-group). The most confusing fact is that it happens even to the caches with persistence (although the data survive restarts). Basically, although persistence is enabled, node restart becomes a destructive operation that requires administrator's attention and causes application downtime. Am I doing something wrong?

afaik default-ds-group and default-volatile-ds-group don't have backups by default. I still suspect that 0 zero backups is the case. Could you please share configurations of affected caches? Are there caches that are not affected by the issue?

"For pure in-memory caches, when a partition is lost, the data from the partition cannot be recovered unless you load it into the cluster again. For persistent caches, the data is not physically lost, because it has been persisted to disk. When the nodes that failed or disconnected return to the cluster (after a restart), the data is loaded from the disk. In this case, you need to reset the state of the lost partitions in order to continue to use the data."
I think this means that whenever a node leaves the cluster, it will check if there are partitions without owners. If a partition has no owner, it will be marked as lost, regardless of whether the data is physically lost. Reset actually clears the set of ids of all lost partitions.
See GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.resetLostPartitions for detial.
Also, try checking the ExcludeNeighbors flag
(see RendezvousAffinityFunction.isExcludeNeighbors())
If the flag is true, nodes located on the same host may not act as backups for each other.

Thank you for your answer. Yes, I saw that piece of the doc and I have two points. First, I use the .Net edition of Ignite, and to my knowledge, there's no .NET API to reset lost parititions. Second, I wonder why I, as an end-user, should worry about managing the internal state of the data store, if it doesn't affect the durability of my data. So far, the need to reset lost partitions when using persistent caches looks like an unnecessary administrative operation that can easily be avoided.

Sorry, I didn't check the question carefully. I used an old version of Ignite. In this version, if the node is just stopped and started immediately without leaving the baseline, the partition loss check will not be triggered. I tested it with version 2.14, and it is indeed unreasonable that the partition loss check will be triggered as soon as the node is stopped. I think this may be a bug.

Yes, it looks like a bug or just something that needs to be changed in Ignite so that no partition loss errors are raised if the partition is durable and the data is still available on the disk. So far I see the only workaround is to create a simple Java app hosting an Ignite node that would periodically check if the parititions in the cluster are operational, and call resetLostPartitions they aren't.
